# Snapping points to nearest points automatically in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, snapping

In ArcMap, is it possible to automatically (through a tool) snap points in one point layer (A), to points in another point layer (B)?

I do not wish to snap the points to a line, nor do I wish to merge the points - I would like the end result to be a new layer (C) containing points from layer A that have been moved to match the nearest point in layer B.  If a separate layer cannot be created, but layer A is altered to match the locations of layer B, that is also fine.  I don't think a spatial join works for me, as far as I understand it, as I want the physical location of one of the point layers to move.

I also do not wish to merge the two sets of points, but keep them separate.

Comment: Have you searched on 'ArcGIS snap points'?  What have you tried?

Comment: I don't wish to merge points. I don't see how this is a duplicate question.

Comment: What I do: use "Near" to identify the closest "To points" for every "From Point".  Add fields "X" (double), "Y" (double) to the "to points" and use Calculate Geometry to get X and Y values for each ToPoint.  with the help of the result of "Near", use "Join Field" to pass the TO X&Y into teh points you want to move.  then use advanced field calculator on the SHAPE field in the From points (forgive the formatting)... .

def movePoint(shape, xCoord, yCoord):
  point = shape.getPart(0)
  point.X = xCoord
  point.Y = yCoord
  return point


movePoint( !SHAPE!, !x! , !y! )

Answer (score 1):

This isn't all that difficult. Just run it through Data Management>Feature Class>Integrate with the rank of your points you want to snap set lower then the points you want to snap to, and some sort of maximum distance to snap across. Should get all your points in the right locations.

Comment: This is a good solution, however, the OP should be advised that there may be duplicate points using integrate. Integrate is often followed up with the Delete Identical tool.

Comment: I've never used the "Snap" tool from the editing toolbox, but they appear to do similar things with crappy data. Generally crappy data remains crappy no matter how much makeup you put on that pig.... crap in... crap out ;)

Comment: I tried to use Integrate but I noticed that it moves both points from the two layers, rather moving Point A to Point B

Answer (score -1):

Without more details, it's hard to give a comprehensive answer to your question. The context in which you're trying to achieve snapping will have a large influence on the possibilities, so I'd recommend you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/224308/edit) your post with some specifics.

I have done a web search on `arcgis snap to points tool` and received the following results which may be of use to you:

- [Use the Snap Geoprocesing Tool to Automate Editing - ESRI](http://www.esri.com/news/arcwatch/0412/use-the-snap-geoprocessing-tool-to-automate-editing.html)
- [Snap Points to Lines Tool - Hawth's Analysis Tools (not updated to latest ArcGIS versions)](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/snappntstolines.php)
- [How to Snap Points to Lines in ArcGIS with Python - Robin's Blog](http://blog.rtwilson.com/how-to-snap-points-to-lines-in-arcgis-with-python/)

Perhaps once you've done some research, you can return to this page and provide your own answer.

Comment: I'm not trying to snap points to lines, but points to points - your second and third suggestion don't apply. Does the first allow the snapping of points to points?

Comment: Yes it does. Just try it. -1 anyway for showing lack of efforts

Comment: My apologies, I did go on a tangent there. However, the third suggestion shows a python script solution for snapping to lines, which I believe could be adapted to snapping to points without a huge amount of effort. The example uses `gp.near` to find the nearest line, however you could implement the same concept for finding the nearest point. There isn't alsways an out-of-the-box solution to all analysis tasks; sometimes we need to patch something together from available parts, or make something from scratch. Most people answering on here would be willing to help, but not do your work for you.

Comment: @FelixIP If I google, and search through this forum, and i google, and I search through this forum, and find no clear method to try, how the hell can I be accused of not trying?  You guys on this site are pretty ridiculous sometimes. You can criticize my searching skills, but I wouldn't post here if I hadn't already actively searched for a long time.

Comment: I search this forum using "snap points". The very 1st return answers your question. Same when you use search window (tools) in ArcGis.

Comment: I too spent a lot of time looking for guidance on snapping points to points. There isn't a lot of clear guidance out there. All of these suggestions are for snapping to lines which doesn't help with snapping points to points.